# How can I animate text to loop like a news ticker around an irregular (neither perfectly flat nor perfectly circular) path?

Tags: javascript, html, css

My goal is to animate text so that it loops around the d-path like a news ticker (except the path is irregular in this case).

- I have tried using @keyframes to increase the startOffset value, but if you set startOffset to a high enough value (try setting it to 50 in the code snippet below), it creates space at the beginning of the text and hides the end of the text instead of looping.
- Since the path is not a perfect circle, simply rotating the whole SVG won't cut it.

```html
<svg viewBox="-10 -10 100 100">
            <path id="MyPath" fill="none" stroke="" d="M 20 20 C 90 0 100 60 40 60 C 10 60 0 30 20 20 Z" />
            <g>
            <text>
                <textPath id="text-path" href="#MyPath" style="font-size: 5px !important; "  startOffset="0">
                    xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
                </textPath>
            </text>
            </g>
        </svg>
```

Comment: Hi, you might add your attempt at the animation or try referring to one of the numerous [examples out on the web](https://www.google.com/search?q=animate+text+along+a+path+svg) on how to accomplish such an effect. Cheers!

Comment: @ChrisW. I've described the attempts I made, which I found from searching the numerous examples out on the web. The problem is that those numerous examples don't work, unless you see one in the link you sent that would work in this context...

Comment: ok then why not include the actual attempt? Or at least whichever got you closest? And yes there's multiple in the search results link that will get you close but to have the continuous infinite effect you're after would require more effort than most folks are willing to volunteer on a Q&A site.

Comment: @ChrisW. The 'closest' attempt was what I described in my post, which is increasing the startOffset continuously, but the actual solution surely will not include that because it just pushes the text out of view. I'd be happy to look at a more specific link than the google search you did for me because none of the ones I am seeing listed in it look like they'll work (or bring me any 'closer' to the solution) in this situation.